How to Extend a Class by decorator with Intellisense Support
I want to accomplish following code with intellisense support. 
"US" should appear in code completion, and "NEWYORK" should appear in code completion.
print(AreaCode.US)          # '5'
print(AreaCode.US.NEWYORK)  # '17'
int(AreaCode.US)            # 5

Edit
My original question was not clear, and it can be rephrased it as follows.
class USCode:
  NEWYORK = 17
  LA = 18

class AreaCode:
  US: MagicalMerged[USCode, SupportsInt] = magical_decorator(USCode(), int_value=5)
  UK: Type[MagicalMerged[USCode, SupportsInt]] = magical_decorator(UKCode, int_value=9)
  MagicString: MagicalMerged[str, SupportsInt] = magical_decorator("Change me", int_value=42)


I need a feature to add SupportsInt to an existing class USCode or str.
Intellisense should be able to recommend member of original class. 
ex) When AreaCode.US is typed, NEWYORK should be suggested. 
(I'm using VSCode with pylance)
Type checker should not complain int(AreaCode.US).

It doesn't matter if SupportsInt is added in metaclass (as with UK) or in normal class (as with US).

Original
Using Metaclass
I found I could use metaclass for int(AreaCode.US) to work.
class MetaclassWithInt(type, SupportsInt):
  def __int__(cls) -> int:
    return cls.int_value  # type: ignore

  def __str__(cls):
    return str(int(cls))

T = TypeVar("T")
def class_with_int(cls: type[T], int_value: int) -> type[T]:
  int_value_p = int_value

  class WrappedClass(cls):
    int_value = int_value_p

  return WrappedClass  # type: ignore

class USCode(metaclass=MetaclassWithInt):
  LA = 12
  NEWYORK = 17

class AreaCode:
  US: type[USCode] = class_with_int(USCode, 5)

The problem
How should I change the code so that I don't have to sepcify metaclass in USCode class declaration? 
I think USCode (or any other class) should be independent with the int_value it has assigned, so I can create new class easily.
For extreme case, I wish I could write as following.
strtype_with_int = class_with_int(str, 10)
print(strtype_with_int)  # '10'
int(strtype_with_int)    # Error: Type "type[str]" is incompatible with type "ConvertibleToInt"

I got rid of metaclass=MetaclassWithInt and tried following.
class USCode:
  LA = 12
  NEWYORK = 17

class AreaCode:
  US = type("US", (USCode, SupportsInt), {})

print(AreaCode.US)  # <class 'abc.US'>
print(AreaCode.US.NEWYORK)  # '17'
int(AreaCode.US)  # Type "type[US]" is incompatible with type "ConvertibleToInt"

class AreaCode:
    US = MetaclassWithInt("US", (USCode,), {"int_value": 5})

print(AreaCode.US)  # '5'
print(AreaCode.US.NEWYORK)  # Attribute "NEWYORK" is unknown
int(AreaCode.US)    # 5

Although second try can give me desired output, the intellisense and type hint is not working.
Another Approach
The solution doesn't have to use metaclass by the way.
T = TypeVar("T")
class WrappedItem[T]:
  t: T
  int_value: int

  def __init__(self, t: T, int_value: int):
    self.t = t
    self.int_value = int_value

  def __int__(self):
    return self.int_value

class USCode:
  LA = 12
  NEWYORK = 17

class AreaCode:
  US = WrappedItem(USCode, 5)

print(AreaCode.US)  # '5'
print(AreaCode.US.t.NEWYORK)  # '17'
int(AreaCode.US)  # 5

Now I just wish to get rid of little t in the middle of US.t.NEWYORK. 
I cannot use __getattr__ because intellisense will not work.
Yet Another Approach: Enums
Comments helped me to look out for enums. 
I guess the most appropriate solution for me is SuperNestedEnum Answer.
However intellisense was not working for nested enum. probably because it used US.__setattr__("NEYWORK", Newyork Enum) to add property of US.

This seems like a good use case for an enum.

@Anerdw Thank's for the suggestion. Maybe I can create US as an enum class, with members NEYWORK and LA. However I couldn't find a way to make int(AreaCode.US) to work with enum. Could you guide me for it?

Rather than using the Enum class, you can use the IntEnum class, which will work with int(AreaCode.US)

"[...] the intellisense and type hint is not working": What IDE are you using?

@InSync I am using vscode. Also using pylance if it is relevant.

Hello, if you try to use an external dictionary and then correlate by class name. Will this achieve the desired effect?

@Jeanneli Thank's for suggestion. I had some time trying to implement as you suggested, but I couldn't find solution. I think I have misdirected my question, so I clarified my question. Could you take a look?

Sorry, if you try to create a new class and then delegate it to that class. Or write a decorator function and try using a decorator. Is this an approach possible?

@Jeanneli I think creating new class and a decorator function is somewhat similar to what I did in The problem section. Although the code is runnable, mypy will complain because mypy lacks Intersection Type. I would try this in a couple of days.
